# Should I speak passively in order to keep the main subject first?

Tags: grammar

For example, I have this sentence:

Galen discovered that when the roosters were bitten by snakes, those that were fed theriac survived, while those that did not died.

Microsoft Word is telling me to change the phrase "when the roosters were bitten by the snakes" to "when snakes bit the roosters." However, the following word "those" addresses the roosters and not the snakes, so how should I phrase this sentence?

Comment: Never give more than passing credence to Microsoft Word's grammar suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, *Word* is not *telling* you to change the phrase. Its advice reads:

> For a livelier and more persuasive sentence, consider rewriting your
>   sentence using an active verb (the subject performs the action,  as in 'The ball hit Catherine') rather
>   than a passive verb (the subject receives the action, as in 'Catherine
>   was hit by the ball') ... .

Microsoft's implicit claim that active sentences are livelier and more persuasive than their passive equivalents is contentious to say the least. There are many contexts in which the passive is much the better choice.

Nevertheless, some writers find it useful to be alerted by *Word* to the passive constructions in their writing so that they can decide whether the active would indeed be the better choice in that context; for instance because they want to avoid the obfuscation that can arise when using the passive. The classic example is: *Mistakes were made*.

In your context the embedded subordinate clause is primarily about roosters not snakes. Hence the passive is the better choice because it allows roosters to be the grammatical subject. And this in turn results in the reader interpreting the antecedent of the pronoun *those* to be roosters and not snakes. So the sentence is fine as it is and *Word's* suggestion in this case can safely be ignored.

Incidentally, did *Word* also object to the passive construction *those that were fed theriac ...* ?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak to Microsoft Word but, thankfully, humans *still* know more about grammar than computers do.

Your logic is not bad. I might not use a pronoun in that spot, but if you will use the pronoun, then the passive is probably better in this instance.